# Чтение из файла по несколько строк со смещением на Python3

Tags: python, циклы

Есть csv-файл на несколько десятков тысяч строк состоящий из набора цифр разделенными « ; »
Нужно считывать несколько строк и записывать в массив. Главная продмема считывать строки по несколько штук, это что-то вроде репрезентативного окна.

Приведу пример, требуется получить 4 первые строки 1,2,3,4 и записать в первую ячейку массива, 
затем считываем 2, 3, 4, 5 строки и помещаем это во вторую ячейку массива, далее смещаемся еще на одну строку вниз и считываем 3, 4, 5, 6 строки и т.д. до конца файла. Т.е. нужно считывать по 4 строки, затем смешать на одну строчку ниже и снова 4 строки, но уже без первой.

**Пример содержимого файла file.csv:**

```
4; 2; 3 
7; 1; 2 
1; 6; 3 
0, 4; 9 
1; 2; 5 
9; 5; 1
```

**На выходе должен получиться такой массив, причем это уже тип float, а не строки:**

```
 a = [   
        [[4, 2, 3], 
        [7, 1, 2],
        [1, 6, 3],
        [0, 4, 9]], 

        [[7, 1, 2],
        [1, 6, 3],
        [0, 4, 9],
        [1, 2, 5]],

        [[1, 6, 3],
        [0, 4, 9],
        [1, 2, 5],
        [9, 5, 1]]
    ]
```

Comment: А что вы планируете делать с получившейся матрицей? Похоже `rolling window` в Pandas - это как раз то, что вам нужно...

Comment: Потом будут применяться функции для поиска корреляций по каждому такому набору. Но хочу понять как организовать сам цикл, без применения библиотек.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Rolling or sliding window iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без использования дополнительных библиотек (`csv` - встроенный модуль):

```
import csv

def rolling_csv_reader(filename, window, dtype=float, **csvparms):
    with open(fn) as f:
        data = []
        for row in csv.reader(f, **csvparms):
            if len(data) < window:
                data += [list(map(dtype, row))]
            else:
                data = data[1:] + [list(map(dtype, row))]
            if len(data) == window:
                yield data
```

Тест:

```
In [149]: fn = r'C:\Temp\data.txt'

In [153]: result = list(rolling_csv_reader(filename=fn, window=4, 
                                           dtype=float, delimiter=';'))

In [154]: result
Out[154]:
[[[4.0, 2.0, 3.0], [7.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 6.0, 3.0], [0.0, 4.0, 9.0]],
 [[7.0, 1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 6.0, 3.0], [0.0, 4.0, 9.0], [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]],
 [[1.0, 6.0, 3.0], [0.0, 4.0, 9.0], [1.0, 2.0, 5.0], [9.0, 5.0, 1.0]]]
```

---

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
In [55]: import pandas as pd

In [56]: fn = r'C:\Temp\data.txt'

In [57]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, sep=';', skipinitialspace=True)

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
   0  1  2
0  4  2  3
1  7  1  2
2  1  6  3
3  0  4  9
4  1  2  5
5  9  5  1

In [64]: df.rolling(4, min_periods=1).corr()
Out[64]:
            0         1         2
0 0       NaN       NaN       NaN
  1       NaN       NaN       NaN
  2       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 0  1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
  1 -1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
  2 -1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2 0  1.000000 -0.944911 -0.866025
  1 -0.944911  1.000000  0.654654
  2 -0.866025  0.654654  1.000000
3 0  1.000000 -0.855689 -0.724335
  1 -0.855689  1.000000  0.316946
  2 -0.724335  0.316946  1.000000
4 0  1.000000 -0.669108 -0.697873
  1 -0.669108  1.000000  0.206383
  2 -0.697873  0.206383  1.000000
5 0  1.000000  0.290914 -0.756377
  1  0.290914  1.000000 -0.428571
  2 -0.756377 -0.428571  1.000000
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Я также хочу сам понять, как построить такой цикл без библиотек.

Comment: @Mavar, реализовать это самому - достаточно тривиальная задача (по-моему). Гораздо сложнее сделать так, чтобы все это быстро и эффективно работало... ;)

Comment: Тут файл не сильно огромен, ждать вполне допустимо. А вот понимание как реализовать цикл, для вас кажется тривиальным, а вот я никак не могу додуматься.

Буду очень благодарен за демонстрацию на обычных циклах, без библиотек.

Comment: @Mavar, добавил "наивную" реализацию...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но этот код (который с импортом csv) на python 3 запустить не удалось.  Много ошибок выдает. А визуально он работает. `def rolling_csv_reader(filename, window, dtype=float, **csvparms):
    with open(fn) as f:
        data = []
        for row in csv.reader(f, **csvparms):
            if len(data) < window:
                data += [list(map(dtype, row))]
            else:
                data = data[1:] + [list(map(dtype, row))]
            if len(data) == window:
                yield data`

Comment: @Mavar, я тестировал этот код под Python 3 - все отлично работало. Какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/add/PycharmProjects/test/ETL-data-test.py", line 28, in <module>

    result = list(rolling_csv_reader(filename=fn, window=4, dtype=float, delimiter=';'))

  File "C:/Users/add/PycharmProjects/test/ETL-data-test.py", line 16, in rolling_csv_reader

    data += [list(map(dtype, row))]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0, 4'`

Comment: @Mavar, а что это у вас за число с пробелом - `0, 4`?

Comment: был слеп. Не распознал из-за неопытности  влияние пробела. Все заработало!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Глаза снова горят. Продолжаю программить

Comment: @Mavar, всегда рад помочь! :)